# Google chrome version 48 JavaScript issue

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, version

We had developed stable website long time back(2 year older). It was working perfectly on Chrome, Firefox as well as Opera.
Since Google chrome had launched the version 48 and 49 beta, My website is completely broken. 
Based on the analysis we observed that,
The code written in beginning in JavaScript file(global code) or code written in document.ready does execute only one time. please note this JavaScript file is imported in dialog box (popup).
When popup is closed and opened again, second time the document.ready code does not execute, seems like browser had stored the file in it and it just does not load the file second time.
example:

JavaScript code:

```
   console.info("top of file");
   $( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
   });
```

when first time this JavaScript is loaded on dialog box open, output would be:

```
top of file
ready!
```

once dialog box is closed and opened again,
No output. Browser should execute the code again as this file in imported in dialog box.

It was working perfectly till chrome version 47.

Please help!!!

Comment: in terms of HTML, what is a "dialog box", how is it being opened, what code runs on the "parent" page when it closes

Comment: dialog box is html code,we could call it pop-up window. that gets displayed on user action.Its like html page, we can include java script files in that. we are using dialog-suggestion to load the popup. code something like this to open the $("#dialog").dialog("open");

Comment: no. Its popup window. like a html page which gets displayed in popup. and user can close it with esc or close button. when this pop up is opened its html code gets loaded in parent html. we reallz feel something wrong with chrome latest release as when we set the cache period to 0 and forced the browser to download the javascript file every time its getting included in jsp. it solved the issue, we can't keep cache period to 0 for performance cause

Answer (score 0):

The above mentioned issue is been resolved with Google chrome version 49(beta).
Seems like Google chrome has fixed the bug, waiting for official stable version launch. Cheers !!!